# How to search an apk folder for integer values

Tags: reverse-engineering

I need to change the value of an in-game currency called credits in an apk. After decompiling the apk on my mac, I opened its folder and spent some time searching for the credits value. And damn, it is near impossible! The code was converted to smali, in which numbers are referred to in hexadecimal form. I even tried searching for the hexadecimal value of the credits in the folder with command f, but I was still thrown into a bunch of confusion (there were a bunch of different hex values, most having nothing to do with the credits, or in part of an incrementing list - you would understand the disaster if you looked at smali). Problem is, I need to be able to search for the value of credits like you would with CheatEngine (for PC/Mac) or GameKiller (for Android). Mind you all, I'm not trying to violate property here, I'm doing it on a test application I have used many times before in my previous posts and reverse engineering, just to put my skills to use in some sort of platform.

Comment: Is your mobile game developed in Java ?

Comment: Yes. Which resulted in the smali conversion when decompiling :)